# namespace ensemble create : limited scope

Tags: tcl

I created this :

```
# file1.tcl
namespace eval myNS {
    namespace ensemble create -command ::make
    namespace export cmd1 cmd2 cmd3
}
```

I've just realised that if I add another procedure `cmd4` to my export namespace in another file like this:

```
# file2.tcl
namespace eval myNS {
    namespace export cmd4
}
```

I can also write like this `make cmd4 $args`

My question is: Is it possible to limit it to `cmd1 cmd2 cmd3` commands?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `-subcommands` option when creating the ensemble to restrict what's available instead of the default of all exported commands:

```
namespace eval myNS {
    namespace ensemble create -command ::make -subcommands {cmd1 cmd2 cmd3}
    namespace export cmd1 cmd2 cmd3
}
```

After loading both files, `make cmd4` will give an error, but `myNS::cmd4` can still be imported with `namespace import` or called directly; just not through the ensemble.

Comment: You can also use the `-map` option, which lets you have full control over what's going on in the argument rewriting engine. (Tcl core ensembles always use that option; it lets the bytecode compiler do smart things.)